# Why isn't the view rendering the action of a control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

So within the layout of my site I've added a RenderAction that looks like this:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("../Controller/Action", new Site.Models.Controller());}
```

The control works fine if I point my browser at `site.com/Controller/Action` but if I try using it within the layout the controller actions aren't executed.

I've also tried:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Controller", "Action", new Site.Models.Controller());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted the parameters. First comes the action name and then the controller name:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new Site.Models.Controller());}
```

or the equivalent:

```
@Html.Action("Action", "Controller", new Site.Models.Controller())
```